# Best way to store text submitted to a Node app from Twilio

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, sms, twilio

I want to make an app where people can text (sms) their name to sign a petition and then their name would be added to a list of signees on a website for the petition.

The sms messages would be handled by Twilio and then be processed by a Node.js app. I would like to use Angular on the front end.

Question: What would be the best way to store the names? Do I need something like MongoDB or would a database be overkill? I'd also like to verify that only one name per phone number is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use a database you'll need to store it in memory. This will mean when you restart the server or it reboots you will lose your names.

So the short answer is yes you will need a database.

As for checking if there are duplicates there are many method with mongodb.

- You can use a find query first to check that it does not exist already.
- You could use `upsert` which will replace a previous one matching one.

However you can use any type of database that you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to vote in favor of a relational database, probably it's a good fit for your kind of project.

Take in account that you can also store some interesting fields that comes with the Twilio request like country and state to list some.

You can take a look at this tutorial where not only you can get the SMS but reply to the user to have a smooth user experience in the process: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-node-js